# I just killed the Son of Crota, but no missions are available

Tags: destiny

I bought Destiny game from PlayStation Network. It gave me the level 25 character boost, as well as unlocking a ton of missions.

After playing a few random missions, I realized you can still play the campaign from mission to mission. Unfortunately, a few of these random missions needed to be played again. So I went to the tower, talked to Eris, and received a new mission.

I just killed the son of Crota, (I believe), and now there are no green and purple icons indicating my next move. Someone please tell me where I go next!

Comment: Are you sure you didn't just recover the "soul" of Crota?  That or you are mixing up his name, in full it is "Crota, son of Oryx."  That said, I'd recommend you stop playing the level boosted character and start another at level 1, then pick the other one back up once you get the second to 25 or 40.

Comment: The level 25 boost was intended to be used to skip year 1 content and begin playing the content including in The Taken King. There should be missions in your quest page which show you what to do next in either case however.

Answer (score 1):

With the new Taken King expansion you should be able to find your quests in your Quest Log. Access this by pressing `Options` and scrolling right, I think it is, and you should see all your missions listed.

You can also check the missions on the Bungie website by logging in, selecting a character, and checking the progress tab.

Here is an example from my Hunter.

[image: Missions progress tab]

Answer (score -1):

Check your Girmore cards. It should tell you which activities are pending.